# Quadratic programming with linear equality constraints in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-regression, system-identification

I have to identify an ARX under some linear constraints, this means that I have a quadratic programming with linear equality constraints problem.

---

One way  is to use the following equations in the red boxes. A possible disadvantage  in this case is the calculation of the matrix inversions (sometimes Matlab gives me the warning:  Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled)

[image]

---

Another way is to use in Matlab the command:   quadprog()

---

Another way is to use in Matlab the command:   lsqlin()

---

Which of these three methods is the best one?

Which is the most robust numerically?

Comment: Hi Simone, could you add working examples for your 3 methods to solve the problem?

Comment: Is the question still alive?

Comment: Yes the question is still alive